# UITableView loading section before particular section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to show `Calendar` into `UITableView`. Each section corresponds to each year of calendar and every section contains 12 cells correspond to 12 months.

I am trying to show 10 years calendar, 5 years back to current date and 5 coming years. 
I can load current year(Section) 2013 as section 0 in `UITableView`. 
But when I scroll Table upward I want to see year 2012 above year 2013. But as 2013 is section 0 so I cant do it though I can insert new sections after current section which is simple.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame logic:(LineKalMonthLogic *)theLogic delegate:(id<LineKalViewDelegate>)theDelegate
{
frame.size.width =  kkLineTileSize.width;
frame.size.height = 31 *  kkLineTileSize.height;

if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    logic = [theLogic retain];
    delegate = theDelegate;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0,1024, 716);
    _mainTable =[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:rect style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    _mainTable.delegate = self;
    _mainTable.dataSource = self;

    _mainTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self addSubview:_mainTable];
    monthHeight = 723;
    backMonthArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    heightArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _sectionNo = 1;
}
return self;
}
-(void)calculateMonths:(int)monthNo{

int i ;
for (i=monthNo; i<monthNo+12; i++) {

    CGRect monthRect = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 1024,723);

    backMonthView = [[[LineKalMonthView alloc] initWithFrame:monthRect andDays: [logic numberOfdaysInMonth:i] andMonthName:(NSString *)[logic gettingMonthDate:i]] autorelease];

    [delegate showForCurrentMonth];

    [backMonthView showDates:logic.daysInSelectedMonth
        leadingAdjacentDates:logic.daysInFinalWeekOfPreviousMonth
       trailingAdjacentDates:logic.daysInFirstWeekOfFollowingMonth];

    [backMonthArray addObject:backMonthView];
    [delegate reloadData];
    monthHeight = backMonthView.frame.size.height;
    [heightArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:monthHeight]];
}
nextMonthNo = i;
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return _sectionNo;    //count of section
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 12; 
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return [[heightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+indexPath.section*12] intValue];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

   [cell.contentView addSubview:[backMonthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+indexPath.section*12]]; //backMonthArray contains 12 months data 

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(indexPath.row == 10 && indexPath.section == _sectionNo-1) //self.array is the array of items you are displaying
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self calculateMonths:nextMonthNo];
        _sectionNo = _sectionNo+1;
[_mainTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:_sectionNo-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    });
}
}
```

So i just want to show sections before current section.

Comment: Can you not implement the UITableView in the order you wish them to display, then scroll programmatically to the section you want to show first?

Comment: EAch month can contains lots of events. So it would take ages to load every year in advance

Comment: It is a UITableView, only the cells on screen will be loaded.